# How to show a portion of next screen in previous one in react -navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am creating tabs in my app using react-navigation by createTabNavigator.
What I want to do is how can I show a portion of next screen in tab in the current screen. The Idea is to show the user that there exist another view
[image: This is what I want to achieve]
What I have already done is that everything except the for showing the next screen in current one, is there any prop or option that will allow me to shrink down the page container?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with `react-navigation`.
Try using a carousel library like `react-native-snap-carousel` (https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel). As you can see in their showcase apps, this library does exactly what you want.

Comment: I have tried it, but the problem was with callbacks they were not properly called
Thanks anyway :)